# Simple way in R to generate an output matrix Z from input vectors x,y and a user defined function f(x,y)

Tags: r

I am new to R. As simple as the question sounds, I haven't been able to find a simple way of doing it in the documentation. So far, the best way I've come up, to generate Z is the below. But surely there is some built in function.

Example for the function [image]

```
grid_size <- 10

x <- seq(0,1,length.out =grid_size) 
y <- seq(0,1,length.out =grid_size)

xgrid <- matrix(x, nrow=grid_size, ncol=grid_size, byrow=TRUE)
ygrid <- matrix(x, nrow=grid_size, ncol=grid_size, byrow=FALSE)


f2v <- function(xgrid, ygrid) { 
  return (1 - xgrid + xgrid*ygrid)
}

Z <- f2v(xgrid, ygrid)
```

Thank you.

Comment: so what is wrong with your solution? If x and y are both vectors, then `x <- seq(0,1,length.out =grid_size) 
y <- seq(0,1,length.out =grid_size)


z <- function(x,y){
  return (1 - x + x*y)
}

z(x,y)`

if they are not vectors and you need to do dot product multiplication, then you can use: `xgrid%*%ygrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outer`:

```
grid_size <- 10

x <- seq(0 ,1, length.out = grid_size) 
y <- seq(0, 1, length.out = grid_size)

t(outer(x, y, function(x,y) 1 - x + x*y))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.